# Java wait()/notify() not working in same object?

Tags: java, multithreading

Essentially, this is what I'm trying to do:

1. A while loop is running some I/O code.  It has a conditional section that executes if a volatile boolean is true.  It then enters a synchronized block with a while loop.  Standard practice.  It calls 'this.wait()' and waits for the notification.

   ```
               while((len=ais.read(buff))>=0) {
               source.write(buff, 0, len);
               if(paused) {
                   synchronized(this) {
                       while(paused && playing) {
                           try {
                               System.out.println("waiting...");
                               this.wait();
                               System.out.println("out of wait");
                           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }

               if(!playing) break;
           }
   ```
2. Other methods in the SAME object change the boolean 'paused' to false.  The method then calls 'this.notify'

   ```
   public void resume() {
       synchronized(this) {
           if(paused) {
               paused = false;
               this.notify();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   The problem is when you call that method, the thread isn't waking up.  The "out of wait" println never even prints.  Why is this?  Can you not do wait/notify within the same object.

**Solved!  Completely forgot that that first part of code (the waiting part) was in a nested class and therefore wasn't the same object.  I came to realize this when I noticed their hash codes weren't the same.**

Comment: How do you know it is the same object? Same object != same class. Can you post the code where you start the threads?

Comment: And you are 100% sure the thread is waiting in this.wait() and not stuck in ais.read() source.write() or elsewhere, and you're certain the resume() method on the proper object is actually called ?

Comment: If you are not doing exercise on wait/notify, since Java 5 there are much better synchronization primitives to achieve your goals.

Comment: Just to double check, is the 'System.out.println("waiting...");' printed out?

Comment: 100% sure the thread is stuck on wait.  And yes "waiting..." does print out.

I am aware of Java 5's concurrency features, as I have used the ExecutorService threading a lot in the past.  But I haven't done much with locks, and I wasn't really planning on trying to figure it out right now...

Comment: Are you sure they are the same object? Can you check if your not calling resume on a different object?

Comment: Got it!  Completely forgot that that first section of code was in a nested class!  *Facepalm*

I guess I just didn't notice it.  I had just restructured it to be Runnable.

Comment: Just as a side note, did you remember to mark the field pause `volatile`? Otherwise, the code is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Are paused and playing declared as volatile? It is possible that one of the threads does not see the other thread's modification of these global variables. Also, we do not know anything about the value of playing.

Comment: Yes they are.  Playing is irrelevant since we're using the AND operator.  The thread is hanging on wait() so it's never even checking the conditions again.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use `notifyAll()` and all should be ok